# Scale (fit) image to area on php without stretching image

Tags: php, image, gd

I need proportional scale by maximal dimension size of area and image by gd.

I have area size:   $Ax$B

I have image size: $ax$b

I need proportional scale WITHOUT cropping picture (function($A, $B, $a, $b)) which will return to me (WidthXHeight) of new image.

Take a look this example:

http://file.qip.ru/photo/Dryu3yhl/two_towers.html?

**UPDATED:**

Image must be resized by max image width/height (but not out of range parent container AxB size).

That scale-algorythm is using simple Windows Picture Viewer.

if imagesize < containersize than imagesize = native image size.
if imagesize > containersize by width it scaled by width,
if imagesize > containersize by width it scaled by height, but not out of range own container.

Big thanks for your answers!

Comment: You can't resize an image without stretching and without cropping. What do you mean? Also in your example the lower image IS cropped.

Comment: The link you give is not consistent to your requirements. The top landscape image shows a square yellow area while the bottom portrait image shows a rectangular yellow area. Please provide more details to your requirements.

Comment: no, one of dimension of target image is equals width or height (by max) of the area. Another dimension of target image is equals propotional size. I need "propotional stretching", but not simple stretching when using scaleX, scaleY (only scaleX or scaleY). I can't explain that more.....

Comment: @user1977306 Please update your question with more explanation and preferably your own test cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this:

```
function new_size($area_width, $area_height, $pic_width, $pic_height) {
    if ($pic_width <= $area_width && $pic_height <= $area_height) return Array('w'=>$pic_width, 'h'=>$pic_height);
    if ($pic_width <= $area_width && $pic_height > $area_height) return Array('w'=>$pic_width*($area_height/$pic_height), 'h'=>$area_height);
    if ($pic_width > $area_width && $pic_height <= $area_height) return Array('w'=>$area_width, 'h'=>$pic_height*($area_width/$pic_width));

    if ($pic_width == $pic_height) {
        if ($area_width > $area_height) return Array('w'=>$pic_width*($area_height/$pic_height), 'h'=>$area_height);
        if ($area_width <= $area_height) return Array('w'=>$area_width, 'h'=>$pic_height*($area_width/$pic_width));
    }


}
```

Comment: var_dump(new_size(500, 500, 900, 900)); not working.

Comment: he must detect image ratio and compare with container ratio; And take effect max dimension of image...

Comment: As i did not test and wrote it quickly there was no control for situation like in your comment. Replaced < to <= in last condition to accept this situation. If you look over conditions you can make it more simpler :-)
now it gives array(2) { ["w"]=> int(500) ["h"]=> float(500) } with your test